# Проблема с Ajax. Не приходит запрос в php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

HTML код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".penter").click(function() {
                $.ajax ({
                    url: "create_page.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: ({pname: $(".pname").val()}),
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function() {
                        $(".suc").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <input type="text" class="pname" placeholder="Text">
        <input type="submit" class="penter" value="Submit">
        <div class="suc">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$pname = $_POST['pname'];
echo $pname;
?>
```

Я не знаю почему, но этот код не передает данные pname в php и не выводит их, как это решить, хотя без ajax с использованием  все работает нормально?

Comment: Код рабочий, проблему воспроизвести не удалось. Перепроверьте еще раз. Советую сделать правильно форму (<form></form>). Поправка: ответ будет дан ниже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропустили аргумент анонимной функции: `success: function()`

Правильный вариант:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: "create_page.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: ({pname: $(".pname").val()}),
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
        $(".suc").html(data);
    }
});
```

Я бы сделал пару правок:

К `input` нужно добавить атрибут `name`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#my_form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url: "create_page.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success: function(mgs) {
            $(".suc").html(mgs);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <form id="my_form">
      <input type="text" class="pname" name="pname" placeholder="Text">
      <input type="submit" class="penter" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <div class="suc">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Почему-то все ещё не работает, учитывая ваши правки

Comment: Обновил ответ. Пропустил атрибут name тега input

Comment: Работает? Если ответ решил вопрос, отметьте его

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
echo $json["pname"];
```